# Using blockquote in chat doesn't work when it's part of a text block

Tags: support, chat, markdown, blockquote

In the chat, when using a blockquote markup after a line of text, the blockquote doesn't render.

For example, if I try:

```
text:  
> quote
```

I get this:

[image]

What's the correct way to use it in this case?

Comment: That's by-design: Markdown in chat doesn't work in multiline messages, as the duplicate explains. Which means the correct way to use it, would be to write and post two messages soon after each other.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell thanks for pointing out the duplicate, I spent 30 minutes on both Google and StackExchange search and couldn't find one ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Tinkeringbell For some values of *by design*. Lots of people still consider it a bug.